# Using widcards in gulp base path

Tags: gulp

Is it possible to use wildcards in the `gulp.src()` base path. For instance:

```
gulp.src('./src/**/*.dll'. {base:'./src/**/bin/'})
```

Say I have these two files:

```
/src/someMiddleFolder/bin/my.dll
/src/someMiddleFolder/bin/someBinFolder/second.dll
```

The result I'm after is (with the dist folder set to `/dist/bin`)

```
/dist/bin/my.dll
/dist/bin/someBinFolder/second.dll
```

Can I achieve this with base option?

Comment: No, the base option doesn't support wildcards.

Comment: Wait, why don't you just use `gulp.src('./src/**/*.dll', {base:'./src/someMiddleFolder/bin/'})` ?

Comment: Well, that as shame it does not support wildcards. The reason I need it is because I have several project folders in my solution. Like this

`/src/domain/[componentName]/bin/` and 
`/src/framework/[componentName]/bin`

Is there some other way i can archive this?

Comment: It's definitely possible, but you would have to edit your question and describe the specific files and folder structure you have and the result you want for me to give an answer.